# TR data-id vindo Null JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

não estou conseguindo capturar o data-id da minha TR.

```js
<script>
    function EditarContato() {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        debugger;
        var url = '@Url.Action("EditarContato","ContatoG", new{area= "Gerencial"})';
        $("#editarContato").load(url +"?id=" + id,
            function() {
                $("#editarContato").modal();
            });
    }
</script>
```

```html
    <tr onclick="EditarContato()" data-id="@item.ContadoId">
                    <td>@item.Responsavel</td>
                    <td>@item.Funcao</td>
                    <td>@item.Celular</td>
                    <td>@item.Telefone</td>
                    <td>@item.Whatsapp</td>
    </tr>
```

o id sempre esta vindo NULL, alguém sabe me dizer o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `$(this)` em `var id = $(this).attr("data-id");` não está se referindo ao elemento clicado, pois o evento em `onclick` está apenas chamando a função. A função, por sua vez, não tem como saber qual elemento a chamou.

O que você poderia fazer é enviar o elemento para a função através de um `this` no onclick:

```
onclick="EditarContato(this)"
```

E na função receber o `this` como parâmetro, para que ela saiba qual elemento que a chamou, e usá-lo no lugar de `this` em `$(this)`:

```
function EditarContato(elemento) {
   var id = $(elemento).attr("data-id");
   ...
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado, era exatamente isso!